# Building VTK emscripten cone example uses outdated VTK version?

Tags: vtk

Currently using Mac OS Ventura 13.3.1

I’m trying to build VTK for emscripten and was able to do so successfully. Now I would like to test my build using the cone example listed here:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/blob/master/Examples/Emscripten/Cxx/Cone/README.md
When I do:

```
emcmake cmake \
  -G Ninja \
  -DVTK_DIR=/work/build-vtk-wasm \
  /work/src/Examples/Emscripten/Cxx/Cone
```

I see the error:

```
CMake Error at /work/build-vtk-wasm/vtk-config.cmake:1 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

/Users/ryanmarr/VTK/build-vtk-wasm/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/vtk-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:139 (vtk_module_autoinit):
  Unknown CMake command "vtk_module_autoinit".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/work/build-cone/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
emcmake: error: 'cmake -G Ninja -DVTK_DIR=/work/build-vtk-wasm /work/src/Examples/Emscripten/Cxx/Cone -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin/node;--experimental-wasm-bulk-memory;--experimental-wasm-threads' failed (returned 1)
```

Is vtl_module_autoinit an outdated command? If so I’d like to find an example that used updated code so I can start using VTK.